# Impossible to add the charm library in Scene Builder

Tags: scenebuilder, gluon, gluon-mobile

I can not add gluonhq.charm elements or open gluon FXML with "charm-common-2.2.0.jar" library in my scene builder Builder 8.2 (I tried with 8.1.1 too).

When I add the jar file, nothing is added in the left section on scene builder.
But the jar is correctly added in the Library folder.

See image below
[image]

Or when I try to open a gluon FXLM, I have this exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Gluon's Charm library, you need `com.gluonhq:charm:2.2.0`, not `charm-common`.

With Scene Builder [8.2.0](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/#download) it is easy to install.

You can follow the documentation [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/scenebuilder/). Basically, you will need to select `JAR/FXML Manager`, click on `Search repositories`, type `charm`, and select `com.gluonhq:charm`.

[image: search charm]

Click `Add JAR` and you'll see all the components that can be added to the Custom Panel in Scene Builder. Finally, click on `Import Components`.

[image: import components]

Comment: Does not work for the latest version of gluon charms (4.0.1)  or is it a paid option now?

Comment: It should work as explained in the answer. No license is required. If it doesn't work for you please create a new question.