# javafxport(gluon) android class dont build

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

i have create a "Gluon Mobile multiple Views with FXML" project. picture of structure and error is attached.
i have these problems:
1- i build android but classes in android section dont build.
2- scene builder dont open fxml becouse of:

> com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<View fx:id="primary" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="350.0" stylesheets="@primary.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gluonapplication1.views.PrimaryPresenter">
<center>

    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <children>
            <TextArea fx:id="txtArea" text="txt area text"/>
            <Label fx:id="label" text="Hello JavaFX World!" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClick" text="Change the World!">
                <graphic>
                    <Icon content="LANGUAGE" />
                </graphic>
            </Button>
        </children>
    </VBox>
</center>
</View>
```

[image][image][image]
[image: structure and error]
Thankful.

Comment: The first issue is related to the NBAndroid plugin. It seems it doesn't play well with the JFXMobile plugin, and you get those warnings. Anyway, the project will compile and run well on Android. Solution: disable NBAndroid. For the second one (known issue as well, to be fixed) launch Scene Builder and open the FXML file with the View, it will load fine.

Comment: thx for help. 1- but classes dont compiled and dont added to apk. 2- i open file but exception thrown: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: src/main/resources/com/gluonapplication1/views/primary.fxmlcom.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
 at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:82)

Comment: Try disabling first the NBAndroid plugin, then reload your project, you should have the Android classes available. Then you can check if you have any error on your code, and fix it.

Comment: Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: /src/main/resources/com/gluonapplication1/views/primary.fxml
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)

Comment: nbandroid is not installed

Comment: For 2, have you installed Charm library on Scene Builder? Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384288/impossible-to-add-the-charm-library-in-scene-builder).

Comment: added but exception appeared. fxml dont opened.

Comment: Even when you open SB first and then load the fxml file?

Comment: yes. closed and reponed and open from recent file but exception repeat.

Comment: Can you post the FXML file? If you have added Charm 4.0.1 jar to SB it should load fine from open/recent files

Comment: As for the NBAndroid plugin, look for "Android" and "Android Gradle Support", category "Mobility".

Comment: Edit your question and post it there

Comment: Android Gradle Support is installed. do remove?

Comment: Yes, or at least disable it

Comment: now that disactivate it. netbeans dont open gluon application project.

Comment: Under the Projects tab, right click on the project's root and select Reload Project. Gradle should manage the dependencies, and once everything is ready it should open it normally.

Comment: dont show it in project pane.

Comment: Make sure you have installed and enabled the Gradle plugin, `Gradle Support`, and disabled the NBAndroid plugin "Android Gradle Support" and "Android".

Comment: very thx. android problem is solved. but scene builder has problem with this exception:
ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon

Comment: What is your Scene Builder version?

Comment: Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 8.2.0

Build Information
Version 8.2.0

Comment: When you open sB, do you see on the left a Custom panel with Charm controls (i.e., `AppBar`, `Avatar`, ...`Icon`, ... `View`)?

Comment: no. what must do?

Comment: I told you a few comments ago, you need to install the Charm library. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384288/impossible-to-add-the-charm-library-in-scene-builder) shows you how. It should install charm 4.0.1.

Comment: its added but is empty for import. pic is add to question.

Comment: Delete it, and click on Search Repositories again, and type `charm-glisten` and add the jar `com.gluonhq:charm-glisten` . Somehow `charm` is not resolving its dependencies.

Comment: very thx. problems solved.

Comment: Since this issue is solved, maybe you should consider posting the answer here. In a separate post, not the comments, I mean. And set the tick, so everybody can see, this issue is solved. Cheers, Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first issue, Android classes failing on NetBeans, the problem is due to having two Gradle plugins colliding: Gradle Support and NBAndroid.

Gluon/JavaFXPorts make use of the Gradle plugin for NetBeans, so this is a must. NBAndroid plugin could be used for logging for instance, but giving that both don't play well together, the solution is just disabling NBAndroid.

Notice that NBAndroid plugin will be under NetBeans->Tools->Plugins, Installed: Android and Android Gradle Support. Deactivate or uninstall both.

[image: NBAndroid]

Restart NetBeans and Android errors will be solved.

About the FXML issue: FXML with Gluon controls (`View`), failing to load on Scene Builder.

There are two issues here:

Install the Charm.jar

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384288/impossible-to-add-the-charm-library-in-scene-builder), using the Jar manager allows searching for `charm` and installing the custom components, once it is found on a repository. Currently, `com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.1` will be resolved.

In case the control list is empty, try searching for `charm-glisten`, and install `com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:4.0.1`. This dependency should be resolved by the `charm.pom`, but it seems it might fail.

The second issue, once charm controls are installed, is related to opening the fxml file from the IDE: Charm controls are not found by Scene Builder and the load fails.

This is a known issue, and it will be fixed in the next release, so for now there are two options:

- Launch Scene Builder, and go to `Open...`, or `Open recent` and open the FXML.
- Edit the SceneBuilder.cfg file (found under `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\app\SceneBuilder.cfg`) and add the path of the installed custom jars to the class path variable `app.classpath=`.